# how to find consecutive delemeters and put space in between in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have like below in a column.

```
1.) $$$$
2.) $FGH$JK$OP$
3.) $oi$$$
```

i want to put space when it find consecutive $ symbol. I am trying this in oracle/PL-SQL.

$ $ $ $

Could anyone please help me here.

Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer again, i fixed some bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (cad,'(\$)\$','$ $ ')
  FROM (SELECT '1.) $$$$ 2.) $FGH$JK$OP$ 3.) $oi$$$' cad FROM DUAL)
```

Results:

```
1.) $ $ $ $  2.) $FGH$JK$OP$ 3.) $oi$ $ $
```

**Edit:**

Bellow query fails in case `$$oi$$$` returning `$ $ oi$ $ $`(check space before `o` character) but now it's fixed:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (cad,'(\$){2}',
  '$ $') ,'(\$){2}',
  '$ $')
  FROM (SELECT '1.) $$$$ 2.) $FGH$JK$OP$ 3.) $$oi$$$' cad FROM DUAL)
 ;
```

This return:

```
1.) $ $ $ $ 2.) $FGH$JK$OP$ 3.) $ $oi$ $ $
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit the regex?

Comment: @Mihai just check  if current char is `$` and next is `$`, then replace both characters by `$ $ `

Answer (score 2):

you can use `regexp_replace`, need to escape $ as it is a regular expression pattern keyword.

```
  SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('$$$$',
                 '(\$)', '\1 ') "REGEXP_REPLACE"
  FROM DUAL;
```